# How do I move multiple columns under specific multiple other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data is something like:

| region | lf_sex_01 | lf_sex_02 | lf_occ_01 | lf_occ_02 | lf_grp_01 | lf_grp_02 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | F | M | 22 | 56 | a | b |
| X | M | M | 54 | 24 | c | a |
| II | F | M | 16 | 34 | d | e |

Where _01 and _02 correspond to individuals living in the same household. This dataset is quite large with up to 20 individuals being accounted for in the same household, and much more characteristics than what I've written down here.

I'm trying to separate these households into individuals, meaning all _02+ individuals get their own row with their matching characteristics for sex, occ, grp, etc, as well as assign them the region their household belongs in.

So, I'm trying to move all sex characteristics in the same column, while maintaining their corresponding region, occ, grp, etc. characteristics (so those have move in one column as well simultaneously(?) such that:

| region | sex | occ | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | F | 22 | a |
| X | M | 54 | c |
| II | F | 16 | d |
| I | M | 56 | b |
| X | M | 24 | a |
| II | M | 34 | e |

I was thinking to first duplicate `region` to all the individuals _01 to `n` and use `np.where` but I can only think of doing it individually as in: moving all sex_02 under sex_01 and then do the same for other columns, but it might take a long time given the sheer size of datasets across years. Is there a way I can do this for for all characteristics of all individuals simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly rename your columns(remove 'If_' from them):

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('_',1).str[-1]
```

try via `wide_to_long()`:

```
out=(pd.wide_to_long(df,['sex','occ','grp'],'region','drop',sep='_')
       .reset_index().drop('drop',1))
```

output of `out`:

```
    region  sex     occ     grp
0   I       F       22      a
1   X       M       54      c
2   II      F       16      d
3   I       M       56      b
4   X       M       24      a
5   II      M       34      e
```

Comment: I tried to do this but it gave me TypeError: wide_to_long() got multiple values for argument 'sep'. Is this because, in the actual dataset, the column names are actually "lfs_sex_01"? sorry I'll edit my post

Comment: @kwispychickyjoy updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Thank you! I copied it exactly but the label names seem to have only retained the numbers now, like: "01 02 03" :0

Comment: @kwispychickyjoy label name?you mean index?

Comment: ah sorry the column names. Instead of sex_01 or occ_01, they've become 01, 02, 03... etc

Comment: I think you can use str.replace, along with a regex to do this. I'll see if i can whip up something and add to your answer

Comment: @kwispychickyjoy I don't know why you are getting columns
names like this...it is working fine on my side btw after running `df.columns=[x.split('_',1)[-1] for x in df]` you are geting names like that?

Comment: no worries @AnuragDabas; there is no need to add anything extra to your code; it works fine.

Comment: @AnuragDabas yeah, I ran it exactly like that so I'm not sure either oof

Comment: @kwispychickyjoy glad it helped...but pls 1 time go through `pd.wide_to_long()` documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pivot_longer` from `pyjanitor` to reshape it, via a regular expression:

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
df.pivot_longer(index='region', 
                names_to = ".value", 
                names_pattern=r".*_(.+)_.*"
               )
 
  region sex  occ grp
0      I   F   22   a
1      X   M   54   c
2     II   F   16   d
3      I   M   56   b
4      X   M   24   a
5     II   M   34   e
```

The ".value" tells the function to keep only the grouped regex( the ones in parenthesis) as headers.

Sticking to Pandas only, the same result could be obtained, using `str.split`, `stack` and `droplevel`:

Set index and split the columns:

```
df = df.set_index('region')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split("_", expand = True)
```

Stack the irrelevant levels, drop them from the dataframe, and reset the index:

```
df.stack(level=[0,-1]).droplevel([-1, -2]).reset_index()

  region grp  occ sex
0      I   a   22   F
1      I   b   56   M
2      X   c   54   M
3      X   a   24   M
4     II   d   16   F
5     II   e   34   M
```

Comment: took a while for me to check since the importing took long but this works wonderfully too, thanks a lot!